# SocketIO broadcasting too fast

Tags: node.js, sockets, heartbeat

I would like to broadcast a single message to every client every second (think about it as custom heartbeat mechanism).

So the NodeJS app is started, sockets are created and when I connect from the client app the heartbeat messages are broadcasted. I'm still developing the client application and that means hitting F5 all the time and reloading the application. The new client SocketIO connection is created on load and this results in heartbeat messages coming to client app with rate much higher than 1 message/sec.

There is nothing special about the code - server side:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ...
  setInterval(function() {
    console.info('broadcasting heartbeat');
    socket.broadcast.emit('heartbeat', /* custom heartbeat*/);
  }, 1000);
  ...
});
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost', { 'reconnect': false, port: 8080 });
socket.on('heartbeat', function(data) { console.log('heartbeat'); });
```

Can anybody give me some advice what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: try to raise the `setInterval()` milliseconds

Comment: where? I don't want to control the rate on client side.

Comment: on server-side. Try to explain somehow what that custom heartbeat is. why `socket.io` events aren't suited for your application? The way you are using the `heartbeat` it ends up storming clients every second with a message.

Comment: That might be strange, but that's what I want to achieve. And I think there might be apps doing the same thing (heartbeating) in the world. I have currently only one client (me testing & developing the app), later there might be groups of clients. The main issue is that the messages are not sent one per sec.

Comment: if the `custom heartbeat` purpose is to ensure that a connection exists the its kind of pointless, when you have events like `on('connection')`,`on('disconnect')`

Comment: Can you please try not to think about it a implementing heartbeat mechanism? I mentioned heartbeats to picture the requirement to do anything every second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to startup up an interval each time.  You can store the intervalID, and even clear it out with `clearInterval(INTERVAL);` when it's not needed.

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(8080);

var INTERVAL;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ...
  if (!INTERVAL) {
    INTERVAL = setInterval(function() {
      console.info('broadcasting heartbeat');
      socket.broadcast.emit('heartbeat', /* custom heartbeat*/);
    }, 1000);
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Good point! I moved the `setInterval` call out of the `io.sockets.on('connection', ...` handler function and it works! Such a stupid mistake I made. Thanks!